# Script installed via pip: /usr/local/bin/ vs /usr/bin

Tags: python, linux, pip

If I install a Python package which provides a script via `pip`, it gets installed in `/usr/local/bin/` on Ubuntu and in `/usr/bin/` on SuSE.

Usually this does not matter.

But I need to maintain `sudo` rules for this script.

I could create two sudo rules for this script. One with "local" and one without.

But that's not the way I want it to be. I want to avoid redundancy.

How can I configure `pip` to always use the same directory (on all linux distros)?

Comment: You should never install packages with `system pip` and definitely shouldn't run `sudo pip`, because you are potentially running dangerous code as root. Please consider using some `virtualenv`

Comment: I install via root: `pip install my_package`. This installs /usr/(local/)/bin/my_script. I create a sudo entry for my_script. No potentially dangerous code gets executed. I don't see any reason why a virtualenv would make this more secure. Could you please elaborate your thought?

Comment: [There are FHS specs for that](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html). `/usr/local/bin` is for executable programs installed past the package manager, e.g. via `make install` or `pip install`. Those files should never land into `/usr/bin` because they wouldn't be tracked by the package manager and can be easily overwritten by another installation. There are also other complications possible. That SuSE allows `pip` to install to `/usr/bin` is IMO this distro's bad habit.

Comment: @hoefling thank you for this hint. This is a known bug: https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1071941 First reported in December 2017.

Comment: I guess until this issue is resolved you will have to keep two rule files, one with the special treatment for SuSE...